# Why does my mass calculation give higher mass after the beta-decay from Thorium-234 to Protactinium-234?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I'm trying to do a mass calculation on the beta-decay of Thorium-234, which I believe goes like this:

Th-234 -> Pa-234 + e + energy

**Masses**

- Thorium-234: 234.043601 u [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_thorium#Thorium-234)].
- Protactinium-234: 234.043308 u [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_protactinium#List_of_isotopes)].
- Electron: 0.000548 u [[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron)].

This gives mass on right hand side of reaction 234.043856 u, which is more then we had in the first place.

What am I doing wrong? Aren't the <s>fission</s> beta-decay suppose to release energy, given by the mass difference?

Comment: Did you use the experimental values for the mass of the two isotopes or did you simply say $m=90*m_{proton} + 44*m_{neutron}$ for thorium? Because that second calculation doesn't account for the mass defect of the binding energy in the nuclei.

Comment: I used *isotopic mass* from wikipedia, I guess those are experimental values. You can follow the links [1], [2] and [3] if you would like to double check.

Comment: Technically this reaction is $\beta^-$ decay, not fission.  "Fission" usually refers to a parent nucleus splitting into two or more daughter nuclei.  (Alpha decay could technically be thought of as fission according to this definition, but it's common enough that it's been given its own name.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In $\beta^-$ decay, you don't actually need to take the mass of the electron into account.  The reason for this is that after the decay, the daughter nucleus still has the same number of electrons orbiting it as the parent did;  but that's one less than it "should have" since the daughter's proton number has increased by one.  The masses given in nuclide mass tables are the masses for the neutral atoms.

In other words, you have
$$
\underbrace{{}^{234}_{90} \mathrm{Th}}_{\text{90 protons, 144 neutrons, 90 electrons}} \to \underbrace{{}^{234}_{91} \mathrm{Pa}^+}_{\text{91 protons, 143 neutrons, 90 electrons}} + \underbrace{\beta^-}_{\text{1 electron}} + \bar{\nu}.
$$
If we say that $m({}^Z_A \mathrm{X})$ is the mass of a *neutral* atom, then the mass before is
$$
m_i = m({}^{234}_{90} \mathrm{Th})
$$
while the mass after is
$$
m_f = \left[ m({}^{234}_{91} \mathrm{Pa} ) - m_e \right] + m_e + m_\nu \approx m({}^{234}_{91} \mathrm{Pa} )
$$
since $m_\nu$ is, of course, negligible.  Thus, the mass defect in the reaction is just the difference in the masses of the neutral atoms.

Note that when you do $\beta^+$ decay, the logic actually works the other way:  the final mass is actually the mass of the neutral atom plus *two* electron masses.  Try going through the logic in a similar way to see why this is so.

Comment: Very nice - the key here is that the mass from the table is for the neutral atom, not the nucleus.